# Javascript Button Value not updating

Tags: javascript

I have this code with three buttons **+**, **0** and **-**.

**On clicking + or -, the value of middle button is not updating.**

The code is :

```js
function add(){
  var x = document.getElementById("val");
  if(x <= 5){
     document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = x + 1;
  }
}
function sub(){
  var x = document.getElementById("val");
  if(x > 0){
     document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = x - 1;
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px #999;
}


.text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #130613;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #999;
}


.button:hover {background-color: white
color: white;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #262626;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Buttons - "Pressed Effect"</h2>

<button class="button" onclick="add();">+</button>
<button class="text"><p id="val">0</p></button>
<button class="button" onclick="sub();">-</button>
```

Please help me in pointing out my mistake, and please do suggest some good button colors for such body background :).

Thanks :)

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("val")` you're getting an _element_, not the text it contains. Besides, you will need to convert `"0"` (character string) into `0` (number) using `parseInt("0")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question and fix your existing code, here's what you need to do : (working snippet)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("val")


function add(){
  var x = parseInt(btn.textContent);
  if(x <= 5){
     btn.innerHTML = x + 1;
  }
}
function sub(){
  var x = parseInt(btn.textContent);
  if(x > 0){
     btn.innerHTML = x - 1;
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px #999;
}


.text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #130613;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #999;
}


.button:hover {background-color: white
color: white;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #262626;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Buttons - "Pressed Effect"</h2>

<button class="button" onclick="add();">+</button>
<button class="text"><p id="val">0</p></button>
<button class="button" onclick="sub();">-</button>
```

**However**, this is a clumsy way of proceeding. A DOM element is not the place where you want to store a variable's value. Here's a cleaner way of doing things :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("val")
var x = 0

function add(){
  if(x <= 5){
    x++;
    updateButton();
  }
}
function sub(){
  if(x > 0){
     x--;
     updateButton();
  }
}

function updateButton(){
   btn.innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px #999;
}


.text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #130613;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #999;
}


.button:hover {background-color: white
color: white;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #262626;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Buttons - "Pressed Effect"</h2>

<button class="button" onclick="add();">+</button>
<button class="text"><p id="val">0</p></button>
<button class="button" onclick="sub();">-</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
function add(){
  var x = document.getElementById("val").innerHTML;
  if(x <= 5){
     document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = parseInt(x,10) + 1;
  }
}
function sub(){
  var x = document.getElementById("val").innerHTML;
  if(x > 0){
     document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = parseInt(x,10) - 1;
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px #999;
}


.text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #130613;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #999;
}


.button:hover {background-color: white
color: white;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #262626;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#191F2F">

<h2>Animated Buttons - "Pressed Effect"</h2>

<button class="button" onclick="add();">+</button>
<button class="text"><p id="val">0</p></button>
<button class="button" onclick="sub();">-</button>
<script>

</script>
</body>
```

You are getting that whole element in x, so to get that `innerHTML` to work, and it returns a string value so you need to parse it using `parseInt`

Comment: When using `parseInt` make sure you supply the radix!

Comment: @Jamiec, Thanx mate updated, bdw i wasnt aware of that as well ;)